# Triggering Web service at regular intervals using Web service Script task in SSIS

Tags: web-services, ssis

I have a requirement to call webservice1 which in turn give call to next webservice2 for calling out user id from SSRS execution logs everyday .Webservice1 will have to be scheduled to occur daily. I searched through various content but not finding solution that could assist in this.

Comment: Can you add an agent job and call your package each day?

Comment: I am not so sure how to call Webservice  through SSIS if i dont have any input and output parameters. Any pointers to how to implement that would be helpful

Comment: You could use a script task. Are there any outputs from the service calls?

Comment: No I dont have any output but i have to make wsdl file dynamically created on each server where it is deployed

Comment: Can you list out example where Script task can be use to call webservice which returns no output. I have been trying to do it using Webservice task in ssis but when i deploy in msdb on ssms on different server , get an error input wsdl file denied.

Comment: Try this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-consume-web-service-through-ssis-package/ it should show you how to dio it.

Comment: Getting forllowing exception -   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you able to debug the web service call to see which line is causing the exception?